# How to know user has removed my application from his page immediately?

Tags: facebook

I want to do something when who has removed my application from his page.

At that time, is there an API event that can catch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There 's the deauthorization callback. If you set the deauthorization callback on your application settings page, everytime a user remove your application, FB will post to your callback URL with that user Facebook ID. You can refer about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), Application De-authorization part.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have try to find the setting place on my application settings page,but I can't find it.Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: otherwise, you can find it naturally by going to the settings page, then go into "Edit settings/settings/advanced"

Comment: Thanks for this info, was looking for something like this.